# Dynamically add edit remove bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a script like edit remove bootstrap tab dynamically. Here is a demo

```js
var button='<button class="close" type="button" title="Remove this page">×</button>';
var tabID = 1;
function resetTab(){
 var tabs=$("#tab-list li:not(:first)");
 var len=1
 $(tabs).each(function(k,v){
  len++;
  $(this).find('a').html('Tab ' + len + button);
 })
 tabID--;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-add-tab').click(function() {
        tabID++;
        $('#tab-list').append($('<li><a href="#tab' + tabID + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab ' + tabID + '<button class="close" type="button" title="Remove this page">×</button></a></li>'));
        $('#tab-content').append($('<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab' + tabID + '">Tab ' + tabID + ' content</div>'));
    });
    $('#tab-list').on('click', '.close', function() {
        var tabID = $(this).parents('a').attr('href');
        $(this).parents('li').remove();
        $(tabID).remove();

        //display first tab
        var tabFirst = $('#tab-list a:first');
        resetTab();
        tabFirst.tab('show');
    });

    var list = document.getElementById("tab-list");
});
```

```css
 #tab-list .close {
     margin-left: 7px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>
                <button id="btn-add-tab" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add Tab</button>
            </p>
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul id="tab-list" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">Tab 1 content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But how to make this editable? I want to edit tab title and tab content. At last how to get the output/html source code in a input?

Comment: Ok, can you clarify the title and question so that it's specifically about *editing the tab titles*, and narrow it down to a single question. " At last how to get the output/html source code in a input?" is a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create an edit function like this..

```
var editHandler = function() {
  var t = $(this);
  t.css("visibility", "hidden");
  $(this).prev().attr("contenteditable", "true").focusout(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("contenteditable").off("focusout");
    t.css("visibility", "visible");
  });
};
```

Then attach the handler to an "edit" button in each newly added tab..

```
$('#btn-add-tab').click(function() {
    ...
    $(".edit").click(editHandler);
});
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/4yGNCaA8Xs